# How to download network-bootstrapper-corda-1.0.jar?

Tags: corda

I am trying to build Corda network where nodes are running on different machines (Note that I am using AWS Corda image where Corda1.0 version is running). I am trying the cordaapp-example CorDapp. I changed p2pAddress of PartyB to my other VM public IP.

I tried to download network-bootstrapper-corda-1.0.jar (as I am using Corda1.0) by using link  http://downloads.corda.net/network-bootstrapper-corda-1.0.jar, but I don't see this 1.0 jar is available and hence I downloaded 3.0 jar and copied to cordapp-example directory. Now, I am running this jar file to create required 'additional-node-infos' files etc. This command is partially executing and putty session getting expired after some time. Below is stack trace.

ubuntu@ip-20-0-0-60:~/dev/cordapp-example$ java -jar network-bootstrapper-corda-3.0.jar kotlin-source/build/nodes/
Bootstrapping local network in /home/ubuntu/dev/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [PartyB, PartyA, Controller, PartyC]
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Node in PartyB exited with 1 when generating its node-info - see logs in /home/ubuntu/dev/cordapp-example/kotlin-source/build/nodes/PartyB/logs
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:136)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$gatherNodeInfoFiles$future$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:44)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:107)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:119)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

In PartyB log file, I see following error 'Invalid command line arguments: just-generate-node-info is not a recognized option'. By seeing this error, I feel that this 3.0 jar can't be used with Corda1.0?

Where can I download network-bootstrapper-corda-1.0.jar?

Answer (score 0):

Versions of Corda before Corda 3 did not require a network map boostrapper. Instead, the network map service was provided by one of the nodes on the network.

See https://medium.com/corda/re-designing-the-network-map-760f62ae8c62 and https://medium.com/corda/cordas-new-network-map-infrastructure-8c4c248fd7f3 for a discussion of why we moved to the new design.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Then, what is the procedure to build network across the nodes in Corda V1.0. (Note that I am using AWS Corda image). Is there any link/document which explains this procedure.

Comment: Joel, the link which talks about downloading the network-bootstrapper.jar only talks about the VERSION as a big string. If you guys could post an example for the VERSION string so that we would be able to figure it out that its meant to be network-bootstrapper-"corda-3.0".jar

Comment: Which link is this?